# Parametric table name for pandas read_sql_query on Postgres

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I cannot find out, how to use `pandas.read_sql_query` and correctly (= **safely against sql injection**) parametrize table names (or other sql identifiers). Using `sqlalchemy+psycopg2` to access PostgreSQL database.

Example of what **doesn't** work:

```
import os
import pandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db = create_engine(os.getenv(POSTGRES_CONNSTRING))
pandas.read_sql_query(sql='select * from %(schema)s.%(table)s',
                      con = db,
                      params={'schema': 'public', 'table': 'table_name'})
```

Yields:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'public'"
LINE 1: select * from 'public'.'table_name'
```

For psycopg2 the correct solution is described [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-usage).

```
import psycopg2
query = psycopg2.sql.SQL('select * from {schema}.{table}') \
                        .format(schema = psycopg2.sql.Identifier('public'),
                                table = psycopg2.sql.Identifier('table_name'))
```

But the query is now of type `psycopg2.sql.Composed`, which I can pass to the execute methods in `psycopg2` but not to `pandas.read_sql_query`.

Is there any good solution to this?

Comment: There is no way to parametrize table or schema names. You can only parametrize the values of columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `as_string` method to turn the `Composed` query into a string that you can pass to Pandas ([docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Composable.as_string)).

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:pw@host:port/db')
cur = engine.raw_connection().cursor()

query = psycopg2.sql.SQL('select * from {schema}.{table}') \
                        .format(schema = psycopg2.sql.Identifier('public'),
                                table = psycopg2.sql.Identifier('table_name'))
query_string = query.as_string(cur)

pd.read_sql_query(query_string, engine)
```